# cannot start up sonatype nexus 2.0.2

Tags: maven, nexus

i run nexus-2.0.2 on linux,
following nexus referrence,
i tried to start up nexus,
using the command:
./bin/nexus console,
then i got these output error:(under win7 is ok)

```
Launching a JVM...
jvm 1    | Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
jvm 1    |   Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.
jvm 1    | 
jvm 1    | 2012-03-15 11:44:21.375:INFO:oejs.Server:jetty-7.5.4.v20111024
jvm 1    | 2012-03-15 11:44:21.419:INFO:ospjc.DisableTagLibsListener:Disabling TLD support for: null (context path: /nexus)
jvm 1    | Starting Jetty...
jvm 1    | 2012-03-15 11:44:21.972:WARN:oejw.WebAppContext:Failed startup of context o.e.j.w.WebAppContext{/nexus,file:/opt/download/nexus-2.0.2/nexus/},./nexus
jvm 1    | java.io.IOException: Stream closed.
jvm 1    |  at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.getNextEntry(libgcj.so.10)
jvm 1    |  at java.util.jar.JarInputStream.getNextEntry(libgcj.so.10)
jvm 1    |  at java.util.jar.JarInputStream.getNextJarEntry(libgcj.so.10)
jvm 1    |  at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.JarScanner.matched(JarScanner.java:152)
jvm 1    |  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.PatternMatcher.matchPatterns(PatternMatcher.java:82)
jvm 1    |  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.PatternMatcher.match(PatternMatcher.java:64)
jvm 1    |  at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.JarScanner.scan(JarScanner.java:78)
jvm 1    |  at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.MetaInfConfiguration.preConfigure(MetaInfConfiguration.java:78)
jvm 1    |  at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.preConfigure(WebAppContext.java:417)
jvm 1    |  at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:453)
jvm 1    |  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59)
jvm 1    |  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:224)
jvm 1    |  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:167)
jvm 1    |  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59)
jvm 1    |  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:89)
jvm 1    |  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:261)
jvm 1    |  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59)
jvm 1    |  at org.sonatype.plexus.jetty.Jetty7$JettyWrapperThread.run(Jetty7.java:142)
jvm 1    | 2012-03-15 11:44:21.992:INFO:oejs.AbstractConnector:Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8889 STARTING
```

Comment: Hmm! works for me upgrading from `nexus-2.0`.  Error seems to indicate an invalid jar.  Was there any manual change?  Or an incorrect/incomplete configuration?

Comment: Installed 2.0.2 yesterday on Linux and had no issues. Try and download the package again and see if the problem is a corrupted binary.

Comment: thanks for replies. centos install a default java(gij), reverse PATH order fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically those IO related issues are either access rights issues or sometimes just an unsupported Java version. Make sure you use Oracle Java 6 or 7. OpenJDK might work depending on the version but is not supported officially for production systems.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes unix system can contain couple of (JVM)

How to check it:

```
$ which java

/usr/bin/java
```

Please check version of this JVM

```
java --version

java version "1.5.0"
gij (GNU libgcj) version 4.4.5

Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

This happens because $PATH contain some kind  of "Search path order". You can easy change it.

Assume that you have installed another version of JVM + JDK

Path to(for example):

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.21
```

Next you should manage PATH. Please add path to bin folder of your JVM
Example:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.21 
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

*Advise: Add this commands to .profile file. This help you, after rebooting, to be ensure that you use correct JVM.*

Finally you can start:

```
./bin/nexus console
```